# Call function in Node.js command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const Twitter = require("twitter");
const keys = require("./keys");
const T = new Twitter(keys.twitter);    

let params = {
screen_name: "TWITTER_NAME",
count: 20
}

function getTweets() {
T.get("statuses/user_timeline", params, gotTweets);
}

function gotTweets(error, data, response) {
if (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: " + error);
} else {
    let tweetLength = data.length;
    for (i = 0; i < tweetLength; i++) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data[i].text + " --- POSTED ON: " + 
data[i].created_at, null, 2))
    }
}
}
```

I am trying to run the function `getTweets()` in Node.js. I want to essentially run something like: **"node app get-tweets"** and have it call `getTweets()` and return the results to me in the terminal. I understand I could just call the function at the end and run **node app**, but I want to add other functions in the same module like `postTweet()`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is by using `process.argv`

```
function getTweets() {
    console.log('getTweets called');
}

function postTweets() {
    console.log('postTweets called')
}

var functionToCall = process.argv[2];

functionToCall && functionToCall();
```

You can execute it by `node app.js getTweets`

The first 2 items in argv will be the path to your node executable and the file you are executing followed by arguments you passed to your app.

Comment: Can I export the function into another .js file and call it like: `node app.js get-tweet.js` ?

Comment: Yes, but if it's in another file you might as well just execute that file.